# Subsetting a named range with another named range

Tags: excel, vba, range, subset

I've two ranges rng1=A1:D10, rng2=C7:D10, I want to access the rng1 cells except C7:D10 in Excel VBA.

Comment: This question seems like it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097144/vba-difference-between-two-ranges

Answer (score 1):

I like Jeeped's answer. Nice and short. But I wonder how it would hold up if the size of the two ranges were increased. Hitting the Union() function for every cell you want to keep has to add up.

So I wrote a completely different solution that does not use the Union function. It does only a handful of range manipulations no matter how big the ranges get, and there is no looping at all.

```
Public Function Difference(r1 As Range, r2 As Range) As Range
    Dim r3 As Range, r4 As Range, s$, x&, y&, x1&, x3&, y1&
    Set r3 = Intersect(r1, r2)  '<-- r1 has priority (what we want to keep).
    If Not r3 Is Nothing Then
        x3 = r3.Columns.Count
        x1 = r1.Columns.Count: y1 = r1.Rows.Count
        x = r3.Column - r1.Column: y = r3.Row - r1.Row
        With r3.Parent
            Set r4 = .Range(r1(1, 1), r1(y1, Application.Max(1, x))):           If Intersect(r3, r4) Is Nothing Then s = s & "," & r4.Address
            Set r4 = .Range(r1(1, x + 1), r1(Application.Max(1, y), x + x3)):   If Intersect(r3, r4) Is Nothing Then s = s & "," & r4.Address
            Set r4 = .Range(r1(1, r3.Column + x3 - r1.Column + 1), r1(y1, x1)): If Intersect(r3, r4) Is Nothing Then s = s & "," & r4.Address
            Set r4 = .Range(r1(y + r3.Rows.Count + 1, x + 1), r1(y1, x + x3)):  If Intersect(r3, r4) Is Nothing Then s = s & "," & r4.Address
            If Len(s) Then Set Difference = .Range(Mid$(s, 2))
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

OP would call it like this:

```
Public Sub Demo()
    MsgBox Difference([A1:D10], [C7:D10]).Address
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

@Jeeped I decided to combine our two methods. I think the result may be the most efficient way to return the Range Difference. If either range has more than one area, then this routine uses your method. If both are one block, my method is used.

I've reworked my method and while it is still the blocking method of before, the entire construction is now done in one Evaluate call. Pretty interesting.

```
Public Function RangeDiff(p As Range, q As Range) As Range
    Dim pp$, qq$, r As Range, rng As Range
    If Not p.Parent Is q.Parent Then Set RangeDiff = p: Exit Function
    Set r = Intersect(p, q)
    If r Is Nothing Then Set RangeDiff = p: Exit Function
    If r.Address = p.Address Then Exit Function
    If p.Areas.Count = 1 And q.Areas.Count = 1 Then
        Const F = "p (o(a:a,,,,c(p q)-1),o(a:a,,c(p q)-1,r(p q)-1,cs(p q)),o(a:a,,c(p q)+cs(p q)-1,,c(p)),o(a:a,r(p q)+rs(p q)-1,c(p q)-1,r(p),cs(p q)))"
        pp = "\" & ChrW$(961): qq = "\" & ChrW$(963)
        With p.Parent: .Names.Add pp, p: .Names.Add qq, q: End With
        Set RangeDiff = Evaluate(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(F, "p", pp), "q", qq), "o", "offset"), "c", "column"), "r", "row"))
    Else
        For Each r In p
            If Intersect(r, q) Is Nothing Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = r
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, r)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        Set RangeDiff = rng
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Blocking the contiguous areas into a range of non-intersecting cells will work for contiguous ranges but what if called as `MsgBox Difference(Range("A1:D10"), Range("B2, C7, D10")).Address` ?

Comment: Yep. Not designed for multi-area ranges. But for two blocks, I think it's pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

```
Sub prac1()
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:D10")
    Set rng2 = Range("C7:D10")
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In rng1
        If Application.Intersect(cell, rng2) Is Nothing Then
            cell.Value = 10

        End If
    Next
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-Union of two worksheet ranges has always been problematic. I find that a helper function helps to reverse the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) and [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx)  methods.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, iWant As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set r1 = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(10, 4) '<~~ Sheet1!A1:D10
        Set r2 = .Cells(7, 3).Resize(4, 2)  '<~~ Sheet1!C7:D10
        Debug.Print r1.Address(0, 0)
        Debug.Print r2.Address(0, 0)
    End With

    Set iWant = whatDoYouWant(r1, r2)
    Debug.Print iWant.Address(0, 0)
    'do something with the iWant range
    Set iWant = Nothing

End Sub

Function whatDoYouWant(rKEEP As Range, rOMIT As Range) As Range
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range

    For Each r In rKEEP
        If Intersect(r, rOMIT) Is Nothing Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = r
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    Set whatDoYouWant = rng

End Function
```

Results from the VBE's Immediate window:

```
main
A1:D10
C7:D10
A1:D6,A7:B10
```